# Alter parent from child?

Tags: html, css

In CSS you can do this:

`nav:hover a {`

But is there a way of changing `nav` when `a` is hovered?

Comment: I have once used a trick based on this article, I guess that is what you want:
http://jeremyjarratt.com/2008/09/css-tricks-styling-parent-elements-with-hover/

Comment: may we show you some jquery or javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the javascript event `onHover`

In jquery, it's something like that:

```
$("a").hover(function () {
    $('#nav').css("color","red");
 });
```

Comment: Kryptix want to change nav on hover of a not nav

Answer (score 1):

#### Coming Soon, to CSS

Explicit subjects in a selector *are coming* in CSS, but we'll have to wait just a bit longer. Soon you will be able to explicitly declare which element is the subject, for instance with your code:

```
$nav a:hover {
    background: red;
}
```

This would change a nav's background to read when any of its anchor descendants are hovered.

Source: Selectors Level 4 » [Determining the Subject of a Selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-selectors4-20110929/#subject)

Until this is implemented, you'll have to use JavaScript (or one of the tools built with it, such as jQuery, Mootools, etc) to accomplish a task like this.

#### Doing it with jQuery

You can accomplish this with jQuery, by adding and removing a class when any of the elements nested anchors are hovered or exited:

```
$("nav").on("mouseenter mouseleave", "a", function(e){
    $(e.delegateTarget).toggleClass("hovered", e.type === "mouseenter" );
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/EPRRy/1/

Comment: So big js code for this small problem. Mr. "Somebody is in trouble" has already given a small script that is suffice to solve the problem using jquery. That script might need some tweak to work for different situation. How is your script different from Mr. "Somebody is in trouble"?

Comment: @sudip The other script didn't preserve the original state. Nor did it work with any anchors that may be loaded after the page has been loaded. Lastly, I do appreciate your comment about this script being verbose - I've shortened it up as a result, yet still preserve the benefits of the original.

Comment: yes.....now it is short and sweet. @jonathan .. Dont get me wrong....I just wanted to know the benefits of your previous script compared the short version that seems to work with some small modifications.

Answer (score 0):

This it the most compatible way

```
 $("a").hover(function () { 
    $(this).parent().css({color:"red"}); 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't a way to ascend elements with CSS. To do explicitly what you described, it would require some JS.

@ssx had it close, but not quite, to do what your are asking with JS (and I'm going to simplify and use jQuery).

```js
$("nav a:hover").hover(function() {
  $(this).parent().css({'color': 'red'});
}), function() {
  $(this).parent().css({'color': 'black'})
});
```

This gives changes the color to read, then back to black when the hover loses focus.

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution for this in CSS 2 (dont know about CSS 3).

Javascript solution is easy and answered by other members.

You can try LESS. Using LESS you can do some conditional styling on DOM.

Comment: None for CSS3 either as shown in Jonathan Sampson's answer. You may want to demonstrate how to use LESS to accomplish this.

Comment: @BoltClock.....I read the LESS documentation but have not got a chance to play with it in any project due to time constraint. Since I am no specialist in LESS, I am also expecting any LESS experts to put some light on this. But, from their documentation it appears to me that its possible to do conditional styling using LESS.

Answer (score 0):

It will soon be intoduced in CSS 4. This is 5 or 6th question of the day i have seen today. I think it should be soon implemented by browser vendors.